# How do I let my HttpUrlConnection return data in JSON format?

Tags: java, jquery, json, get, httpurlconnection

I have a `HttpUrlConnection` between a Java application and a web application. On the Java application I have the code:

```
exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.getBytes().length);
exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("content-type", "application/json");
exchange.getResponseBody().write(response.getBytes());
exchange.close();
```

I think the wrong code is in the second line, but I can't figure out how I should do this. exchange is of type `HttpExchange`.

the string response contains: `{ batteryMax: 22000, batteryCharge: 860, carRange: 350 }`

I retrieve the data with the following code:

```
var jsonData;
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://145.93.73.69:8080/getInfo", function(data) {
    jsonData = data
})
.error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

`error` always gets alerted, `jsonData` stays undefined and `jqxhr.responseText` contains `{ batteryMax: 22000, batteryCharge: 860, carRange: 350 }`.

What do I have to change in order to make this work?

Comment: Check the console, what is the error? is `145.93.73.69:8080` your website?

Comment: You string response isn't valid JSON.

Comment: You should use quotation marks for keys and values as @Arun Killu described.

Comment: 145.93.73.69 is where the Java application runs on. The console doesn't show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
                //JsonNode df = mapper.readValue(response, JsonNode.class);
                byte[] responseInBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(response);
```

I use Jackson to make a JSON node from the String I had (+single quotes arround the keys) and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Json must be like this

```
{ "batteryMax": 22000, "batteryCharge": 860, "carRange": 350 }
```

Comment: Yep, field names must be JSON strings, as per RFC 4627, sections 2.2 and 2.5.

Comment: even the value to be quoted if not a number ?

Comment: I am talking about field names (well, member names to be exact). As to member values, if they are strings, well, they must be strings, yes. Here, values are JSON numbers and as such must not be quoted. `22000` is a JSON number, `"22000"` is a JSON string.

Comment: You're right and I changed that. It didn't change the problem though

Comment: are you using jsonp ? is the json contents in your server or from another?/

Comment: No, I don't use jsonp. The json content is on the Java server.